# Accessing Kafka broker from outside my LAN

Tags: networking, apache-kafka, portforwarding

I start-up a plain Zookeeper/Kafka broker using the default commands below as these are described in the [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) in one machine (let's call it **Machine A**)

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

These start a broker at localhost:9092 in Machine A.

I then go to another computer (let's name it **Machine B**) which is on the same network and create a default consumer provided by Kafka by calling this

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server IP_ADDRESS_HERE:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Where IP_ADDRESS_HERE is the IP address in the local network of Machine A that hosts the broker (e.g., 192.168.1.10)

Everything works fine. Then I try to access the broker from a machine outside of my local network (let's call it **Machine C**). I go to my router configuration and I do a port forwarding for the machine that hosts the broker (Machine A). For example I do the following

```
192.168.1.10:9092 --> 9094
```

Meaning that I forward the internal 9092 port of the 192.168.1.10 device (Machine A) to port 9094 of my router. I then go to a service like the [YouGetSignal](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and check if port 9094 of my **public** IP address (e.g., 97.190.92.128) is open. And I get a message that indeed the port is open.

When I try to consume the borker in Machine A from Machine C using the following command

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS_HERE:9094 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Where the PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS_HERE is the public IP address of the network where Machine A is in (e.g., 97.190.92.128). However, I get an error that cannot connect to 192.168.1.10:9092 - broker might not be available (notice that the internal IP:port is returned in the error which means that my router provides the info correctly)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update `advertised.listeners` in your `server.properties` to give a host/IP and port combination that your *client* can resolve and connect to.

As you've observed, the broker gives out `192.168.1.10:9092` in response to a client connecting to it, which will work fine for any machine on the same network (including Machine B).

For Machine C the broker needs to tell it how to connect to the broker, which if I have followed correctly is `PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS_HERE:9094`.

If you need to connect from both your LAN and WAN, you'll need two listeners; one for LAN and one for WAN. In `server.properties` put:

```
listeners=LISTENER_LAN://0.0.0.0:9092,LISTENER_WAN://0.0.0.0:9094
advertised.listeners=LISTENER_LAN://192.168.1.10:9092,LISTENER_WAN://PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS_HERE:9094
listener.security.protocol.map: LISTENER_LAN:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_WAN:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=LISTENER_LAN
```

Note that you need to change your port forwarding, so that the endpoint on your broker is the port as defined for `LISTENER_WAN` (9094). If a WAN connection tries to connect to the broker on 9092 then it will be given the `LISTEN_LAN` details (which is what's happening at the moment, and won't work).

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Thanks. I did follow the suggestion (although I have tried this previously) and I get exactly the same error. (I guess that in the advert. listeners it should be port 9092 not 29092 that you have and it is a copy-paste typo)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo

Comment: Did you restart your broker, and update your port forwarding? It's unlikely you got the exact same error if you've done these steps precisely. Maybe you could edit your question to also include the output of `$ kafkacat -b <host:IP> -L` for the permutations of config that you're trying.

Comment: Ooops I forgot to change the port forwarding in the router. It now works!!! Thanks a lot!